# i want to add a client logo image in the Navigation Bar and Tab Bar iOS

Tags: ios, navigationbar

in my application (base SDK 4.3) the client wants to add his logo at 2 places
1. Navigation bar - (the bar button items are called from code).
i have already tried this:

```
UIImage *myImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo40.png"];
UIBarButtonItem* test= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
```

but results in a white image 
I want to Display Image big as Navigation bar.

2.TabBarController - here i have 5 Tabs in application , the client wants his logo at the botton right Corner .

is there any way to get a colorful logo ?

Comment: The logo at the bottom right corner of the tab bar is a bad idea and results in a poor UX, the tab bar already has icons/tabs and crowding it with a logo is simply too much, and if you've got the logo on the navigation bar, why duplicate it again at the bottom?

Comment: my client have 2 logos of its product so one at Navigation bar and another at Tab Bar.
Even i too thought its a bad idea to put logo on tab bar, but still its demand of clint so trying to find a way to satisfy his desire .

Answer (score 1):

Try this for add image in navigation bar,

```
// Add image
UIImageView *notifyImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
[notifyImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Notifier.png"]];


UIBarButtonItem *notificationButtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:notifyImage];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:arrayWithObject:notificationButtn animated:YES];
```

Comment: dude i tried this but came to crash of app :( 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f37b80' , what else i have to do ??

Comment: @VinayChopra Try now. I have updated my answer. No need to use setLeftBarButtonItems here. Just use setLeftBarButtonItem. Also setLeftBarButtonItems is the new feature..

Comment: I am sorry to say , as i am Fresher to iOS. again Crash !!
Instance Method setBar Button Item not Found  , i have made a mutable array named array with object. can you provide me some detail what should i do .

Comment: finally this worked for me ..
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
UIButton *face = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
face.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
[face setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *faceBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face];